# O que é uma Improper List no Elixir?

Tags: lista, lista-encadeada, elixir

O que é, e pra que serve `improper list` do modulo [List](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/List.html) do Elixir?

Ele recebe uma lista e retorna um `boolean`, se a lista é `improper` ou não

```
improper?(maybe_improper_list()) :: boolean()
```

Graças ao [Pattern matching](https://elixirschool.com/pt/lessons/basics/pattern_matching) nós podemos dividir uma lista entre o primeiro elemento e o restante dele `[head | tail] = list`

Conseguimos fazer coisas como essas pra adicionar um elemento no incio da lista encadeada.

```
iex> list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
iex> [5 | list]
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Quando eu tento adicionar um único elemento no final dessa lista, eu tenho coisas como essa:

```
iex> list = list ++ 5
[1, 2, 3, 4 | 5]
```

E ao testar essa lista com `improper list` ela retorna `true`

```
iex> List.improper?(list)
true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: as `improper lists` (ou listas impróprias) são um tipo de lista que se caracteriza por não possuir uma lista vazia como último elemento do seu último par (ou `cons`).

Exemplo:

A lista `[1, 2, 3]` também ser escrita `[1 | [2 | [3 | []]]]`, o que a torna uma lista normal (não imprópria).

Já a lista `[1 | [2 | [3 | 4]]]` é imprópria, pois o último elemento do último par da lista é o número `4` e não uma lista vazia.

```
iex> List.improper?([1, 2, 3])
false

iex> List.improper?([1 | [2 | [3 | 4]]])
true
```

Sobre a concatenação, para não gerar uma lista imprópria, ela pode ser feita de duas maneiras:

```
iex> list = [1, 2, 3]

# Opção 1
iex> [0 | list] # recomendado (tempo constante)
[0, 1, 2, 3]

# Opção 2
iex> list ++ [4] # não recomendado (tempo linear)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

A opção 2 não é recomendada pois possui um tempo linear, ou seja, é necessário percorrer a lista inteira para incluir o elemento).

No geral, as listas impróprias não são muito utilizadas e devem ser evitadas, exceto para alguns cenários específicos, como, por exemplo, quando se está trabalhando com `iodata`.

Para saber mais sobre o assunto, recomendo o seguinte conteúdo: [Making sense of Elixir (improper) lists](https://dorgan.netlify.app/posts/2021/03/making-sense-of-elixir-(improper)-lists/)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).